# Dismiss Modal view controller with tap AND/OR edge swipe

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on an iOS app with lots of gestures integrated for navigation.
When certain items are tapped, a modal view controller slides up with options to select inside, and a 'done' button across the top of the view to dismiss said modal VC.

The 'done' button doesn't quite 'feel' right as there are so many other gesture-based controls throughout the app, and I was wondering if: **anybody out there know of an (easy) way I could integrate a 'swipe from the top edge of the screen' to dismiss this modal?**

I don't want to get rid of the 'done' button, though. Hope that makes sense! Currently, my modalVC's *.m file's got:

```
-(IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender
{[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; }
```

in there… Pretty straightforward. Tapping the 'done' button totally works, too. No problems at this point

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to achieve this.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] 
    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(userSwiped:)];

swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;

[modalController.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];

//Action method
- (void)userSwiped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; 
}
```

iOS uses swipe from top corner to display the Notification centre. It's therefore not recommended to relate this gesture to any action in your app.

The above sample recognises a top to bottom swipe anywhere on the modal view and dismisses it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!
Took me some googleing to figure out what to do with all that trash, but this was helpful! I appreciate it!

Comment: Want to Know how to set the Speed of the Swipe , it is happening very fast and i can not hold the ViewController in Between the Swipe.